# No Response After Running Python Script Using Python-Shell

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, no-response

I have a nodeJS application and I need to run a python script in order to get a certain response. I am using python-shell in order to do that, but I am getting no response.

I have tried also using a child-process, same response.

Here I call the python script:

```
var ps = require('python-shell');
ps.PythonShell.run('./face_detect.py', array1, function (err, data) {
    if (err) req.send(err);
    req.send(data.toString())
});
```

This is a snippet of my python script:

```
import cv2
import sys
import os
import numpy as np

students = sys.argv[1]
# get the names and put them in an array ---> subjects
imagePath = "class/welcome.jpg"
cascPath = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

.....
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    num = 0
    crop_img = cv2.UMat(image[y-40:y+h+100,x-40:x+h+40])
    cv2.imwrite("face" + str(num) + ".jpg", crop_img)
    test_img = cv2.imread("face" + str(num) + ".jpg")
    num = num + 1
    predicted_img1 = predict(test_img)
absences["A"] = 1
for name, a in absences.items():
    if a == 0:
        noshow.append(name)
print(noshow)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I expect it to return an array. 
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What is the result of that final print before the `cv2.waitkey(0)`?

Comment: It's an array of strings

Comment: Does the array `noshow` you are printing have the data you are looking for?

Comment: yes it does, my problem is the function in nodejs is returning empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [correct syntax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell#running-a-python-script-with-arguments-and-options) for passing argument from Nodejs *python-shell* to Python script is:

```
ps.PythonShell.run('./face_detect.py', { args: array1 }, function (err, data) { ... })
```

Here the value of `sys.argv[1]` in your Python script will not contain the Nodejs `array1` value because you don't set the `args` property in your PythonShell options.

Note also this should probably be `res.send` instead of `req.send`, depending on your program, and I advise you to `return` if there is an error to prevent "headers already sent" exception.